# TFS: How do I add undo unchange to action in Visual Studio2019?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2019, tfvc

How can I add the following plugin to Actions, Visual Studio?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to install the [TFS Source Control Explorer Extension for VS2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-2019)

Download the extension file "`TFSSCExplorerExtension.vsix`" -> Close any active VS instances -> Double click the .vsix file to install the extension.

After that, start VS2019, check the behavior in the Team Explorer.